# Wix custom ui, default text in edit control not shown

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3

I have developed a custom dialog for WIX. I need to set default values for edit controls and so far I got this:

```
 <UI Id="DlgDbSettingsUi">
      <Dialog Id="DlgDbSettings" Width="370" Height="270">
        <Control Id="BannerLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="44" Width="370" Height="0" />
        <Control Id="BannerBitmap" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0" Width="370" Height="44" TabSkip="no" Text="!(loc.InstallDirDlgBannerBitmap)" />
        <Control Type="Text" Id="lblHeader" Width="333" Height="17" X="8" Y="56">
          <Text>Por favor, especifique los siguientes datos requeridos para la configuración de.</Text>
        </Control>
        <Control Type="Text" Id="lblIp" Width="78" Height="17" X="11" Y="82">
          <Text>IP de base de datos:</Text>
        </Control>
        <Control Type="Edit" Id="txtIp" Width="190" Height="15" X="98" Y="82" Property="DATABASE_IP" />
        <Control Type="Text" Id="lblPort" Width="50" Height="17" X="11" Y="101">
          <Text>Puerto:</Text>
        </Control>
        <Control Type="Edit" Id="txtPort" Width="190" Height="15" X="98" Y="101" Property="DATABASE_PORT">
          <Text>1521</Text>
        </Control>
        <Control Type="Text" Id="lblInstancia" Width="50" Height="17" X="11" Y="120">
          <Text>Instancia:</Text>
        </Control>
        <Control Type="Edit" Id="txtInstancia" Width="190" Height="15" X="98" Y="120" Property="DATABASE_INSTANCE">
          <Text>DEFAULT_INSTANCE</Text>
        </Control>
        <Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" ElevationShield="no" X="240" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUIOK)"/>
        <Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Cancel="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUICancel)"/>
        <Control Id="BottomLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="234" Width="370" Height="0" />
      </Dialog>
    </UI>
```

However, when I run the installation, my custom view is showing empty edit controls. Is nesting a Text tag inside Control edit tag the way to go? Am I doing something wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the default values in the properties tied to each edit control.

Comment: Thanks for you time. I also tried with <Control Type="Edit" Id="txtIp" Width="190" Height="15" X="98" Y="82" Property="DATABASE_IP" Text="Default Value"/> with same result, edit box is still empty.

Comment: Give `DATABASE_IP` a value.

Comment: How? Could you explain your answer?

Comment: Use the `Property` element.

Comment: Ok, I got it, I need to create a Property element with same name as the one assigned to edit's Property attribute, like <Property Id="DATABASE_PORT" Value="1521" />. Thanks.